# creating an array of stringbuffers

Tags: java, arrays, declare, stringbuffer

I'm trying to create an array of stringbuffers by:

```
StringBuffer[] rotor={"jndskfnjl","kjbsdbfkj","njkfdn"};
```

and it shows error "string cannot be converted to stringbuffer".
but I can create an array of strings without any problem and I can create declare individual stringbuffers in a similar manner as strings without having to convert them.

Please tell me how I can make an array of stringbuffers.

Comment: Add the language tag, Java or?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: sorry, i added java tag now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to go through and create the `StringBuffer` objects yourself.  It's not an object like `String`, where you can create a new one without a constructor; you actually have to instantiate *each* occurrence.

```
StringBuffer[] rotor = {new StringBuffer("jndskfnjl"),
                        new StringBuffer("kjbsdbfkj"),
                        new StringBuffer("njkfdn")};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an array of `StringBuffer`, It will expect list of objects of same type. It will not convert `String`s to `StringBuffer` object. Because these two are completely different types in java. `StringBuffer` provides a constructor for creating object using string literals. You need to call them manually.

You can convert `String` array into `StringBuffer` array, iterating over a loop.

```
String array[] = new String[]{"jndskfnjl","kjbsdbfkj","njkfdn"};
StringBuffer buffers[] = new StringBuffer[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
  buffers[i] = new StringBuffer(array[i]);
}
```